# How to do this symbol integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I don't know how to calculate this integral

```
Integrate[x^(-3)*Exp[a/x]*(Erf[b/(Sqrt[2*x])]^(k - 1))*(1 + (1/Sqrt[2*Pi])*
      Erf[b/Sqrt[2*x]])^(n - k), {x, 0, +\[Infinity]}]
```

It's seem a hard question,the *Maple* also cannot solve it.

Comment: I think that is more of a math question rather than a Mathematica question. do you want to try asking in https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @MauricioLobos But I don't want to know how to calculate it in detail,I perfer to know its result by software. :-o

Comment: do you have reason to expect an analytic result?

Comment: @george2079 It's in my research,and maybe will be useful.